# What influences offline coin generation?

Tags: best-fiends-forever

It's clear there is some sort of influence on what the game considers a "day's worth of gold" since the package in the store always contains more coin the next time I look at it.

What influences the increase in generation of coins while I'm away from the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing the game for so long and being familiar with it very well now i know that its mostly about the total fiends damage the more damage they have the more the 1day worth of gold will be